# Yii2 kartik GridView work uncorrect

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have adjusted the widget like:

**> import kartik/grid/GridView**

```
{{ use('kartik/grid/GridView') }}
```

**> use GridView::widget(...)**

```
{{
    grid_view_widget(
        {
            'dataProvider': dataProvider,
            'export': false,
            'responsive': true,
            'condensed': true,
            'toolbar': [
                '{export}',
                '{toggleData}'
            ]
        }
    )
}}
```

but the table was cut and toolbar wasn't shown:
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $columns,
'pjax' => true,
'condensed' => true,
'panel' => [
    'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title">' . $this->title,
    'before' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['create'],
            ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) . ' ' .
        Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', ['index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
],
'export' => false,
'toolbar' => [     
    '{toggleData}'
]])
```

With this atleast your toolbar will be shown. Let me know what happens. :)